# Retain dropdown box selection after submit - PHP

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

Is there any way I can enable drop down boxes to retain their selection after the user hits the submit button? Currently it retains information entered to text boxes, however I am unable to apply this to both my select boxes and my radio buttons.

Here is my html code for the select box:

```
<strong>Select Party Size* :</strong>
<select name="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="5">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option value="10">2 People (£10)</option>
<option value="15">3 People (£15)</option>
<option value="20">4 People (£20)</option>
<option value="25">5 People (£25)</option>
<option value="30">6 People (£30)</option>
<option value="35">7 People (£35)</option>
<option value="40">8 People (£40)</option>
<option value="45">9 People (£45)</option>
<option value="50">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>
<span id="partySize" class="error"><?php echo $partyErr;?></span>
```

Here is the php for said select box:

```
if($_POST['party']=="") {
    $partyErr = "Please select the party size";
} else {
    $party = test_input($_POST["party"]);
}
```

Here is also my radio buttons which I would like to apply this to:

html:

```
<strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br> Yes (+£5)  <input type="radio" name="vip" value="yes">
<?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="yes");?>
<br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br> 
No  <input type="radio" name="vip" value="no">
<?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="no");?>
```

php:

```
if (empty($_POST["vip"])) {
    $vipErr = "Please make a VIP area selection";
} else {
    $vip = test_input($_POST["vip"]);
}
```

Comment: When you submit the form you are changing page. You can store $_POST inside (as example) sessions. Than on your first page you can check: if is setted something than checked = checked

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know how something like this could be implemented? Currently i am not redirecting the user to another page, I am just validating the information entered once the user hits the submit button and I wish for the select/radio boxes to hold their selection after the user hits submit

Comment: The submit do not change page?

Comment: @MarcoMura not yet, planning to implement that later, first I want to get validation running and this is the last step I need to implement

Comment: to achieve that you need to do the "submit" with ajax. That done the user won't change the page, so you do not need to do anything to mainten the "selection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your HTML. The `select` tag does not have a `value` attribute, [you need to set](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select_pre) `selected` on the appropriate `option` element. Similarly [radio buttons use](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp) the attribute `checked="checked"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how would this look once implemented to my code? could you give me a functioning example?

Comment: I've added some links to my answer. You need to do at least a tiny bit of research yourself.